# How to perform dedup in python?

Tags: python, pyspark, window, partition-by

I have a data frame. Now I want to partition by one column and orderby with descending order with one column. Although I know how to do it in Pyspark using sql but not clear of doing it in python. My pyspark code is as follows:-

```
df= Name    age
    Ram     20
    geet    16
    ram     50
    geet    15
    tom     21
    hary    25
    tom     36

partition_col=['Name']
arrange_col =['age']
df= df.select("*",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(partition_col).orderBy(*[F.desc(c) for c in arrange_col ])).alias("Value"))

this gives me:-
df=
    +----+---+-----+
    |Name|age|Value|
    +----+---+-----+
    | Ram| 20|    1|
    |geet| 16|    1|
    |geet| 15|    2|
    |hary| 25|    1|
    | ram| 50|    1|
    | tom| 36|    1|
    | tom| 21|    2|
    +----+---+-----+
```

Now I want the same in python. how do I code this:-

```
df.select("*",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(partition_col).orderBy(*[F.desc(c) for c in arrange_col ])).alias("Value"))
```

Into python?
As there is no option of `window.partitonBy`

Comment: I don't understand the question, that is Python?

Comment: @fam-woodpecker the code is in pyspark. I want the same process to be happen in python.

Comment: Pyspark is a module in python. The code you wrote in pyspark, is written in python and is not SQL. Do you mean to do the same thing with something like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and not using pyspark?

Comment: @fam-woodpecker Oh, yes.